# progressdialog crash in AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

My `ProgressDialog` crashes when I call `AsyncTask` class.
`AsyncTask` throws following error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

This is how i call my `AsyncTask` class from `Activity` class

```
new CopyToSDHelper(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + fileName, context, fileName, numberOfContact).execute();
```

And this is my AsyncTask class

```
public class CopyToSDHelper extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void>
{
    // Notification Manager
    private NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
    // Current API version
    private int                 currentApiVersion;

    String                      fileName        = "";
    String                      backUpFileName  = "";
    String                      numberOfContact = "";
    Context                     context;
    ProgressDialog              dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_background_submit_dialog);
    }

    public CopyToSDHelper(String fileName, Context context,
            String backUpFileName, String numberOfContact)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.backUpFileName = backUpFileName;
        this.numberOfContact = numberOfContact;
        this.context = context;

        this.currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        // Call Notification method
        displayNotification();

        WebDavWriter writer = new WebDavWriter(context, fileName);
        try
        {
            int progress = Integer.parseInt(numberOfContact) / 100;

            publishProgress(progress);
            writer.sendFileToKiki(backUpFileName);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            // Now delete local file from Android
            File file = new File(fileName);
            file.delete();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            new ErrLog(e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        try
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And this is Logcat result

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): Process: example.sample.android.SDcontactlist, PID: 29186
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:540)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at write_helper.CopyToSDHelper.onPreExecute(CopyToSDHelper.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at utils.SaveAllEntry.vcfSection(SaveAllEntry.java:281)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at utils.SaveAllEntry.access$10(SaveAllEntry.java:246)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at utils.SaveAllEntry$4.onClick(SaveAllEntry.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(29186): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for any help.

Regards

Comment: post your activity_background_submit_dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and came to conclusion that you are using a `Context` like `getApplicationContext()` instead of an `Activity` context.

Note that this is the same `Context` which is passed to `Toast.makeText()`.

Comment: Dear Sufian. Thanks for reply. I have changed as you suggested unfortunately crash again and throws this message : android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Your answer gave me new vision and i solved problem. Solution was simple. I used ClassName.this instead of getApplicationContext(); Hope this help somebody else.